# Disable fields from Cs Cart Admin panel

Tags: php, html, cs-cart

[image]

Hello

Is there a way to disable editing the information from the fields displayed in the image?

I tried looking into template hooks but didnt find anything useful yet.

FYI: The information has to be displayed but not editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for disabling email go to **design/backend/templates/views/profiles/components/profiles_account.tpl** :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label cm-required cm-email">{__("email")}:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="user_data[email]" class="input-large" size="32" maxlength="128" value="{$user_data.email}" disabled/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: URL : http://localhost/cscart/ca_panel.php?dispatch=profiles.update&user_id=249&user_type=C

Comment: If you are looking to disable "billing address" fields, use this path : design/backend/templates/views/profiles/components/profile_fields.tpl

Comment: Or if you looking to disable "user account information" fields  design/backend/templates/views/profiles/components/profiles_account.tpl

Comment: I have created custom profile fields, which has to be disabled as shown the question

Comment: the blockchain address is displayed under contact information